# Using Eloquent and pivot with models, which have various relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to retrieve data using Eloquent, however I have several relationships between my models. I have four database tables (with the first three also having models):

```
- users (user_id, username, email ...)
- account (account_id, ...)
- entry (entry_id, account_id, ...)
- account_users (user_id, account_id)
```

In entry, account_id is a foreign id and the relationship has been implemented in both models.
account_users is an intermediate table for account and users. I have created a many-to-many relationship between account and user by adding the belongsTo-method in each respective model.

In Entry.php:

```
    public function account(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Account', 'account_id');
    }

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
    }
```

In Account.php:

```
    public function entry(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Entry', 'account_id');
    }

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'account_user', 'account_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

In User.php:

```
    public function accounts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account', 'account_user', 'user_id', 'account_id');
    }
```

In EntryController I have the method index(), where I am trying to show just the entries belonging to the currently logged in user, however I'm not sure how to structure the select query. I've read in the Laravel documentation about using pivot when structuring a query, however I'm still unsure.

Comment: You have to first target the `account_users` where you will be able to get currently logged in user detail.

Comment: `account_users` from here you will make a relationship with `account` by `account_id` and from `account` you go to the `entry` model.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir Thank you for your reply. I understand that I need to get the user_id of the currently logged in user, then compare this with the id in account_users and then only show the entries with the correct account id, however I can't manage to code this. Can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a variable `$user` exists, you may do this to retrieve entries:

```php
$user->load('accounts.entry');

$entries = $user->accounts
    ->flatMap(function ($account) {
        return $account->entry;
    })
    ->unique('entry_id');
```

It will get entries from every account and merge them into a 1-dimension array, and finally remove the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however it didn't work. The view loaded, however there weren't any entries when there should've been. Do you have any idea why?